# how to capture a single frame using gstreamer

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

I am using the following command to capture multiple frames:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.2 port=5000 num-buffers=100000000  ! gdpdepay ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! multifilesink location="frame%05d.jpg"
```

I would like to capture a single frame and for the gstreamer to close gracefully afterwards.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research we have got to the following solution:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.2 port=5000 num-buffers=100000 ! gdpdepay ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! pngenc snapshot=true ! filesink location=a.png
```